# Different interpretations window.getComputedStyle(myElement)['right']

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got problem with different browser interpretations of **window.getComputedStyle** method.

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<div id="myElement">Element content</div>
```

**This is CSS:**

```
#myElement{
  position:fixed;
  left: 20px;
  top: 0;
}
```

**And the JS:**

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement'),
right = window.getComputedStyle(myElement)['right'];
```

The problem is that the **'right' variable differs depending on the browser**. It's caused by the fact that 'right' property isn't declared

- On Firefox it gives me an **integer with 'px' suffix** (which is what I want),
- On Chrome and IE11 it gives me **"auto"**

Is there a method that I can call to get the the integer with 'px' suffix in chrome and IE? I know I can go around it and get the window width and substract "left" property from it along with the element width, but it doesn't seem elegant.

Oh, and I need to use vanilla js only.

Comment: I don't think there's a nice way to get unified `right` property the way you described, from the element object. Indeed, the workaround would be to get the bounding boxes of elements, and substract, as: http://jsfiddle.net/92L5wwd0/

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle for an explanation of the implementation differences. But to the element’s width in pixels, including padding, use `clientWidth` or (to have border included in the count) `offsetWidth` instead; they work even when the width is not set in CSS but determined by defaults or by HTML attributes.